# Installation configuration Stripe

Tags: stripe

Bonjour,

J'aimerais savoir si qqn peut m'Expliquer comment installer et configure Stripe et pouvoir configurer mon civicmemberships

=== From Google Translate:

Good morning,

I would like to know if someone can Explain to me how to install and configure Stripe and be able to configure my civicmemberships

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE.  Stripe installation instructions are here:  https://docs.civicrm.org/stripe/en/latest/install/

If anything is not clear, do ask more specific questions.